# Multinomial Coefficient example

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multinomial-coefficients

A teacher will divide her class of 17 students into four groups to work on projects. One group will have 5 students and the other three groups will have 4 students. How many ways can students be assigned to group if:

All group work on the same project?

since there's no order i think the right answer would be :

**$$ \frac{\binom{17}{5 ,4,4,4}}{4!}$$**

But in my notes the professor said $$ \frac{\binom{17}{5 ,4,4,4}}{3!}$$

I don't see any particular reason.

Maybe it is because we're trying to make the 3 groups of four look the same ?

Is a multinomial coefficients used to distribute those 17 people with taking in account that the 4 groups are different, and dividing that by 3! means we can arrange those groups in 3! ways ?

Comment: The group of $5$ is distinguishable from the three groups of $4$ students by its size.  The factor of $3!$ is needed since the order in which the groups of $4$ are selected does not matter.

Comment: Why would you make it distinguishable?

Comment: As I said, it has a different size than the groups of $4$.

Comment: I still don't see why intuitively you'll want to make the 3 distinguishable. Since when you're using the multinomial coefficient you're assuming that these groups are different. Or is it just a by convention where when given n groups of the same size you have to use that factor of (1/n!) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it this way. Arrange the students in a line (there are $17!$ ways to create this permutation):

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc}
s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6 & s_7 & s_8 & s_9 & s_{10} & s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & s_{14} & s_{15} & s_{16} & s_{17} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17
\end{array}
$$

Then create the groups by taking the first 4, second 4, third 4 and last 5:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc|cccc|ccccc}
s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6 & s_7 & s_8 & s_9 & s_{10} & s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & s_{14} & s_{15} & s_{16} & s_{17} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17
\end{array}
$$

Every way to group the students can be created this way. The key question is: how many permutations lead to the same set of groups?

> N. B. we want the bars in these exact positions. If we allow ourselves to place the bars differently we would have to multiply $17!$ by $4$ to include the extra data of where the group of $5$ is taken from (first, second, third or fourth group).

We see of course that we can permute the people in any of the 4 groups and it doesn't change the group. Example:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc|cccc|ccccc}
s_3 & s_2 & s_4 & s_1 & s_6 & s_5 & s_7 & s_8 & s_9 & s_{10} & s_{12} & s_{11} & s_{14} & s_{13} & s_{17} & s_{15} & s_{16} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17
\end{array}
$$

There are $4!$ ways to permute each of the first three groups and $5!$ ways to permute the fourth group. This brings us down to $\frac{17!}{4!4!4!5!}$.

Also note, that when we do this, there is an inherit order to the three groups of $4$. Specifically, things like this:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc|cccc|ccccc}
s_5 & s_6 & s_7 & s_8 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_9 & s_{10} & s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & s_{14} & s_{15} & s_{16} & s_{17} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17
\end{array}
$$

is considered different. There are $3!$ ways to permute the groups of $4$ leading to the final answer of

$$ \frac{17!}{4!4!4!5!}/3!. $$

Note that we cannot swap a group of $4$ with a group of $5$ because that would require moving the bars. The goal we started with is to count how many of the $17!$ permutations lead to the same groups of students by placing the bars after the fourth, eighth and twelfth student.

Comment: I fully understand now thank you

Answer (score 3):

What matters here is which students are assigned to which group.  The group of $5$ people is distinguished by its size.  The groups of $4$ are distinguished by who is in which group, not the order in which the groups are selected.

Let's say the professor selects the following groups:

$$\{A, B, C, D\}, \{E, F, G, H\}, \{I, J, K, L\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

There are six ways to obtain the same groups, depending on the order in which the three groups of $4$ are selected.

$$\{A, B, C, D\}, \{E, F, G, H\}, \{I, J, K, L\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

$$\{A, B, C, D\}, \{I, J, K, L\}, \{E, F, G, H\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

$$\{E, F, G, H\}, \{A, B, C, D\}, \{I, J, K, L\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

$$\{E, F, G, H\}, \{I, J, K, L\}, \{A, B, C, D\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

$$\{I, J, K, L\}, \{A, B, C, D\}, \{E, F, G, H\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

$$\{I, J, K, L\}, \{E, F, G, H\}, \{A, B, C, D\}, \{M, N, O, P, Q\}$$

Therefore, we need to divide by the $3!$ orders in which the groups of $4$ can be selected.